# Double value used as argument for the StringBuilder's deleteCharAt() method

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm preparing for Oracle Associate Certification and am reading the following book :

*Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE7 Programmer Study Guide*

At the page 77, there is a knowledge test with the following question :

> Given the following declaration :
>
> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
> Which of the following are valid uses of the sb variable?
>
> a. sb.append(34.5); b. sb.deleteCharAt(34.5); c. sb.toInteger(3); d.
>   sb.toString();

I assumed the right answers were a & d.

But here's the answer from the book :

> a, b, and d There is no StringBuilder toInteger method.

With no other explanation.

So, I went to check the Source Code and here it is :

```
279    public StringBuilder deleteCharAt(int index) {
280        super.deleteCharAt(index);
281        return this;
282    }
```

Taking an `int` as an argument and the method is not overloaded anywhere else.

Do you know an explanation to this "correction" in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake in the book.  Your answer is correct, it should be only a & d.  Here is a link, 
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/10143
and find the following errata heading (about midway in the page):
Errata type: Technical | Page number: 297 | Errata date: 5 Feb 2013

Answer (score 1):

For the example given above `sb.deleteCharAt(34.5)`

The compiler says

> The method deleteCharAt(int) in the type StringBuilder is not
>   applicable for the arguments (double)

Then the book's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it looks like an error in the book, you may want to contact the publisher about it.

while you can cast 34.5 to an int,losing precision, its not happening in answer B.